# Facebook event RSVP with Graph API Error ( This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-oauth

I'm using this code to make a Facebook application that can Accept / Decline events (RSVP) on my Website.

```
<?php

//BOTOES RSVP ( ATTENDING - MAYBE - DECLINED)
$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
$my_url = "xxx";
$rsvp_status = "";
$festaid = '281914068631280';


$code = $_REQUEST["code"];


if(empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=rsvp_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");


}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);




if( isset($_POST['rsvp']) ) {
    // Form submitted, call the Graph API to RSVP to the event
    $event_rsvp = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $festaid . "/{$_POST['rsvp']}?method=post&" . $access_token;
    $rsvped = json_decode(file_get_contents($event_rsvp));
    if($rsvped) {
        $msg = "Your RSVP status is now <strong>{$_POST['rsvp']}</strong>";
         $rsvp_status = $_POST['rsvp'];
    } else { $msg = "Tem algum problema"; }
}

if( !$rsvp_status ) {
    $query = "SELECT rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=$festaid AND uid=me()";
    $fql_url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?"
        . "query=" . urlencode($query)
        . "&format=json"
        . "&" . $access_token;
    $fql_resp = json_decode(file_get_contents($fql_url));
    $rsvp_status = $fql_resp[0]->rsvp_status;
}

?>

<?php echo $event_rsvp ?>

<?php if( isset($msg) ) { ?>
<p id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
<?php } ?>


<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="privacy_type">RSVP:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="attending" <?php if($rsvp_status==="attending") echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Attending&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="maybe" <?php if($rsvp_status==="maybe" || $rsvp_status==="unsure") echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Maybe&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="declined" <?php if($rsvp_status==="declined") echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Not Attending&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="RSVP to this event" /></p>
</form>


<?php echo 'MEU STATUS' . $rsvp_status; ?>
```

However, when I click the button Attending for example, the code returns the following error:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/281914068631280/attending?method=post & {"error": {"message": "This authorization code has been used.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100 }}
```

Could you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Did you use the Authorization code twice? (the code where you're setting `token_url`)

Comment: Pretty sure that you are trying to exchange the code for an access token twice here somehow, otherwise you would not get this message (unless it is an FB bug, which I doubt however). I can only recommend that you use the PHP SDK instead of dealing with login yourself – it handles all that perfectly for you in the background, so there is no need to handle that yourself (especially as doing it yourself obviously has increased potential for messing things up).